# Find cubic equation using known points

Tags: cubics

I'm writing a javascript game, and are working on some interpolation functions, but I don't have enough mathematical knowledge to work out this problem.

I want to use a cubic function for interpolation with this formula:

```
y=ax^3 + bx + c
```

I want to find `a` using two points `[x1,y1] [x2,y2]`

`b` and `c` are known values.

- `b` is the 'slope' of the equation, and determines how 'curved' the returned results are (sorry about the bad explanation), and is set by the program
- `c` is equal to y2

Is it possible to solve for a, using only these two points?

My ultimate goal is to interpolate (or map) any value `x`, that is between `x1` and `x2`, to a value between `y1` and `y2`, in a non-linear way, determined by this equation.

Let me know if I need to explain some things better.

Edit: Example of how it would work:

Points are defined as [0,0] [100,1000]

Given an x-value 50, a linear interpolation would return 500.

A non-linear interpolation (possibly cubic) would, depending on the slope, return a value higher or lower than 500.

Comment: It is not possible. In fact, such an $a$ will not always exist. If $c = y_2$, then is it true that you want $x_2 = 0$? If so, then it is possible to solve for $a$, and you can do it in the naive way: plug in $(x_1, y_1)$ since you know both $b$ and $c$, and solve for $a$.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. I'll add an example of how the equation would work in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two equations in one unknown, so will usually not have a solution.  From the first point alone, you can write $a=\frac{y1-bx1-c}{x1^3}$  The second point gives you a similar equation.  If the two $a$ values agree, all is well.  If not, which do you choose?  Only one of your points will be on the curve.

Comment: Yeah, this was not the right way to solve my problem. I ended up finding a solution using Bezier curves, based on a quadratic equation.